# Finite dimensional k[x]-module is torsion module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $R=k[x]$. Let $M$ be a $k[x]$-module which is finite dimensional as a $k$-vector space. I want to prove $M$ is a torsion module.

I’m wondering how to build a relationship between basis and torsion, because from the question, all I know is $M$ has a basis of size $n$ ( assume the dimension is $n$).

Comment: The archetypal $R$-modules which are finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces are the quotients $R/(f)$, for any non-zero polynomial $f\in R$. You should start with those. See what you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $m\in M$.

Since $M$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, the infinite sequence
$$m,xm,x^2m,...$$
of elements of $M$ can't be linearly independent.

It follows that for some nonnegative integer $n$ there must exist $c_0,...,c_n\in k$, not all zero, such that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^im=0
$$
hence $pm=0$, where 
$$p=\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i$$
so $m$ is a torsion element.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Apply the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to the $k$-endomorphism given by multiplication with $x$.

Answer (score 0):

*By contrapositive*:

> If $M$ has non-torsion elements as a $k[X]$-module, it can't have finite dimension as a $k$-vector space.

Indeed, let $m\in M$ such that $\operatorname{Ann}_{k[X]}=\{0\}$. Then, the submodule $k[X]m$ is  isomorphic to $k[X]$ as a $k[X]$-module, hence as a $k$-vector  space, and the latter is not finite dimensional over $k$.