# Paolo Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0 - rational canonical form Theorem VI.7.5 vs Theorem VI.5.6?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In Chapter VI, Theorem 7.5 states that

> Let $k$ be a ﬁeld, and let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Let $α$ be a linear transformation on $V$ , and endow $V$ with the corresponding $k[t]$-module structure, as in Claim 7.1. Then there exist monic nonconstant polynomials $f_1(t), \cdots, f_m(t) \in k[t]$ such that $f_1(t) | \cdots | f_m(t)$ and
> $$
> V \cong \frac{k[t]}{(f_1(t))} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{k[t]}{(f_m(t))}
> $$
> as $k[t]$-modules.

Theorem 7.5 is an application of Theorem 5.6, which says

> Let $R$ be a PID, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then there exist nonzero, nonunit ideals $(a_1),\cdots , (a_m)$ of $R$, such that $(a_1) \supseteq (a_2 ) \supseteq \cdots \supseteq (a_m)$, and an isomorphism
> $$
> M \cong R^{\mathrm{rk} M}\oplus \frac{R}{(a_1)} \oplus \cdots \oplus \frac{R}{(a_m)}
> $$

> The rank $\mathrm{rk} M$ of a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ is the maximum number of linearly independent elements in $M$.

Comparing these two theorem, the rank of V $\mathrm{rk} V$ is missing from Theorem 7.5. Is rank of $V$ zero as an $k[t]$-module? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: $\dim_k V$ is finite, unlike $\dim_k k[t]$

Comment: Can you explain a bit further? $k[t]$ isn't the module, it's the underlying ring...

Comment: What would $V$ having nonzero rank as a $k[t]$-module entail?

Comment: It means there exist $v \in V$, $p(t) v \neq 0 \, \forall p(t) \in k[t] \, p(t) \neq 0$. Therefore $v, t v, t^2 v, \ldots$ are linearly independent, which is impossible since $\mathrm{dim}_k V$ is finite.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962161/finite-dimensional-kx-module-is-torsion-module